# Insert only that values that are in database field in ASP.NET with EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

**I am new To EntityFramework and Also ASP.Net**

I am creating an authentication system in Asp.net MVC5 with EF and i have following fields in my db

```
Id | Name | Contact | Url | Username | Password
```

and I have my model `Clients.cs` with a class `Clients` that need to be stored in database:

```
public class Clients
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public long? Contact { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Site Url")]
    public string Url { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Password Mismatched. Re-enter your password")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm Password")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

}
```

And I try to store the Credentials as shown below:

```
//Controller::

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Index(Clients clients)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Clients client = new Clients();
            client.Name = clients.Name;
            client.Password = clients.Password;
            client.Url = clients.Url;
            client.Username = clients.Username;
            client.Contact = clients.Contact;

            dbContext.Clients.Add(client);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("api/products");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

It shows an error:

```
Server Error in '/ProductsApp' Application.

Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

Source Error:


Line 32: 
Line 33:                 dbContext.Clients.Add(client);
Line 34:                 dbContext.SaveChanges();
Line 35:                 return RedirectToAction("Index");
Line 36:             }
```

How do I store all fields in database except `ConfirmPassword` field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem With the Help of [Marthijn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/788840/marthijn)

I changed the Clients Confirm Password as:

```
[Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Password Mismatched. Re-enter your password")]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "Confirm Password")]
[NotMapped]
public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

and Controller's code as:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index(Clients clients)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        dbContext.Clients.Add(client);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View();
}
```

and it worked....
Thanks to [Marthijn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/788840/marthijn)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`NotMappedAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.notmappedattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
[NotMapped]
public string MyProperty { get; set; }
```

Your property will become:

```
[Required]
[Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Password Mismatched. Re-enter your password")]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "Confirm Password")]
[NotMapped]
public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

Comment: do i need to remove `[Required]`

Comment: No, you can (and should) use the other attributes as well (I didn't copy-paste them in my answer). I updated my answer so it's a bit clearer.